# Spinner animation during long operations gets hang, how to avoid it?

Tags: extjs

I have an application that takes quite long to save the data as it has to write over intranet. I want to run an animation showing that saving is in progress. How to do it? Any code examples?

While loading huge data the spinner animation gets hang after some time.

Comment: You should provide the precise version of ExtJS you are using

Comment: Hemant: could u plz share some codes for more clarity?